# TypeError: LoginPage.userNameTextBox.setValue is not a function

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io

Getting the below error while trying to run program for webdriverio using cucumber

TypeError: LoginPage.userNameTextBox.setValue is not a function
at World. (C:\Users\Desktop\Webdriver_cucumber\features\step-definitions\steps.js:21:31)
at World.executeAsync (C:\Users\Desktop\Webdriver_cucumber\node_modules@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:136:25)
at World.testFrameworkFnWrapper (C:\Users\Desktop\Webdriver_cucumber\node_modules@wdio\utils\build\test-framework\testFnWrapper.js:45:32)

**login.feature** file

```
Feature: To test the login functionality in "The Internet Herokuapp"

Background:
      Given the user is on login page


Scenario: The one where user logs in using valid credentials

  When the user enters username as "tomsmith" and password as "SuperSecretPassword!"

  And clicks on login button

  Then the user must navigate to secure area page displaying a message "You logged into a secure area!"


Scenario Outline: The one where user logs in using invalid credentials

When the user enters username as "<username>" and password as "<password>"

And clicks on login button

Then the user must remain on login page displaying a message "<errorMessage>"

 Examples:

| username  | password              | errorMessage       |

| james     | SuperSecretPassword!  | Invalid username!  |

| tomsmith  | SuperPassword!        | Invalid password!  |
```

**steps.js**

```
When('the user enters username as {string} and password as {string}', function (username, 
password) {


LoginPage.userNameTextBox.setValue(username);

LoginPage.passwordTextBox.setValue(password);

});
```

**shim.js**

```
async function executeAsync(fn, retries, args = []) {

this.wdioRetries = retries.attempts;
try {
    return await fn.apply(this, args);
}
catch (e) {
    if (retries.limit > retries.attempts) {
        retries.attempts++;
        return await executeAsync.call(this, fn, retries, args);
    }
    throw e;
}
}
```

Anyone could please help?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already have found the solution or not as this question I see is already 7 days old.
Did you try to put a `wait` before `LoginPage.userNameTextBox.setValue(username);`. It's really difficult to answer anything without looking into the page definition or element definition. But in most cases, it happens because the page is still loading but the code has already been executed and resulted in calling a function on the element which is not available yet. Maybe try to put a `wait` just to debug.